# LUKS and Windows

Tags: windows, encryption, luks

I love LUKS encryption of disks under Linux. Sadly LUKS is not available under Windows. I was wondering if  it is possible to encrypt a disk with LUKS and put a windows filesystem on top. And if yes, how would the unlocking work? This is relevant for external, portable SSDs which are shared around and mainly used in my Windows Laptop environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shallow uncooperative user would say: use Bitlocker, it is embedded in Windows 10 ^__^

But there's more, fortunately: **LibreCrypt** and LibreCryptExplorer. You can find the installer and source in [github](https://t-d-k.github.io/LibreCrypt/).

It is an elder project, still on beta. But I use it happily since years, and it grants me the Linux/Windows interoperability in term of encryption (with luks of course).

The GUI is 90's style, but it works fine.